# How to include the execute and canExecute parameters of Command constructor into a single method in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, command

I have the following code

```
public partial class CopyViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

    public ICommand CancelCmd { private set; get; }

    public CopyViewModel(string clickedDeckName, string clickedDeckDescription)
    {
        CancelCmd = new Command(
        execute: () =>
        {
            var a = 1;
        },
        canExecute: () => 1 < 2);
    }
}
```

But i would like to be able to just write something like this:

```
CancelCmd = new Command(CancelMethod);
```

But how should I code the `CancelMethod` with both the `execute` and a `canExecute` included?

---

Also, i am getting the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### PART 1

What i normally do is something like this:

```cs
SGTryAgainCommand = new Command(
    execute: SGTryAgain, 
    canExecute: SGTryAgainCanExecute);
```

where

```cs
private void SGTryAgain()
{
    // Do something
}
```

and

```cs
private Boolean SGTryAgainCanExecute()
{
    // Evaluate if command can execute!
}
```

---

If you move `SGTryAgainCanExecute()` inside `SGTryAgain()` like this:

```cs
private void SGTryAgain()
{
    if (SGTryAgainCanExecute())
        SetInstanceOfSyncGateway();
}
```

then you might be able to achieve what you are looking for, and call simply

```cs
SGTryAgainCommand = new Command(SGTryAgain);
```

### WARNING

I would strongly discourage you from doing that since it would have some disadvantages like:

- If you bind the `Command` to a `Button`, then not setting explicitly `canExecute` will cause the `Button` to be enabled even if it can't execute. That is a nice behavior from `Button`, acctually: to be able to appear disabled if `canExecute` returns `false`.

---

### PART 2

### How to fix the error you are getting

As for the error you are getting, you can change your code as follows:

```cs
OKCommand = new Xamarin.Forms.Command(execute: (x)=>OK(), canExecute: OKCanExecute);
```

### Why are you getting that error?

The `Command` constructor has two overloads

```cs
Command(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
Command(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
```

In your code, since the function you are using for canExecute has signature

```cs
// Takes an object and returns a boolean
Func<object, bool> canExecute)
```

you are implicitly opting for the overload where your functions take an argument, and thus you are forced to accept an argument in your execute method! So you have to write either

```cs
// just ignore the x object...
OKCommand = new Xamarin.Forms.Command(execute: (x)=>OK(), canExecute: OKCanExecute);
```

as mentioned above, or you have to modify  your OK method signature and define like

```cs
private void OK(object x)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

in which case you would be able to write again

```cs
OKCommand = new Xamarin.Forms.Command(execute: OK, canExecute: OKCanExecute);
```